# Basic scanf statement error

Tags: c, if-statement

I am writing a basic program to tell the user whether or not they have received enough sleep. However no matter how many hours are entered it always displays the first message of "Sleep Deprived" even if they've slept 10 hours.

```
double hoursOfSleep;

printf("Please enter the amount of hours of sleep you received last night:\n");
scanf("%f", &hoursOfSleep);

if (hoursOfSleep <= 4){
    printf("Sleep deprived!\n");}
else if (hoursOfSleep <= 6){
    printf("You need more sleep.\n");}
else if (hoursOfSleep <= 8){
    printf("Not quite enough.\n");}
else
    printf("Well Done!\n");
```

Comment: No repro: https://ideone.com/klbxit

Comment: Have you considered printing out the value of `hoursOfSleep` so you can see what the program has got, and can compare it with what you think the program should have gotten?  It is the most elementary of debugging techniques (print out the input for checking).  It would tell you the trouble, too — your code isn't reading the input correctly.  It's also something you can and should check if you're using a debugger instead of printing as your debugging technique.

Comment: Many compilers, with warning well enabled, will warn about `double hoursOfSleep; ... scanf("%f", &hoursOfSleep);`  You can save yourself time by fully enabling your compiler's warnings or look for a new compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
scanf("%lf",&hoursOfSleep);
```

Because you specified `%f`, you told `scanf()` to expect a `float *`, but you passed it a `double *`.  Using `"%lf"` specifies that you are requesting a double value (passing a `double *`).

Comment: %lf specifies that you are requesting a double

Comment: @AndrewL. you got it.

Comment: @J.MarcosHernandezQ.  You can, and should, edit your answer to improve it, rather than leaving comments.  I added the material for you this time, but you should do it yourself in future.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have a format specifier for a floating point number in your `scanf()`. You should use `%lf` for a double:

```
scanf("%lf", &hoursOfSleep);
```

When you don't match the format specifier to the type of the variable in a `printf()` or `scanf()`, you will have an unexpected result. When I entered 6 while running your code on my system, the `float hoursOfSleep` held the value 0.000000.

This sort of problem can be caught at compile time by enabling some compiler warnings. For example, I always at least have:

```
gcc nosleep.c -Wall -o nosleep
```

The `-Wall` switch enables several warnings, and the second I compiled your code I could see what was wrong. In fact, I would urge you to try compiling your broken code with the `-Wall` switch to see what happens. This kind of thing happens all the time; it is easy to forget one of the variables on the right side of a `printf()`, and with warnings enabled you find it right away.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, you must use `%lf` for `double` when using `scanf`. This is a bit confusing as doubles are printed with `%f` but that's how it is.

What I want to add is: **Always check the value returned by `scanf`**

Your current code has undefined behavior if the user inputs something not being a double. So at least do:

```
if (scanf("%lf", &hoursOfSleep) != 1)
{
    // Add error handling here
    hoursOfSleep = 8;  // At least initialize the variable...
}
```

A better approach could be:

```
char input[100];
while(1)
{
    printf("Please enter the amount of hours of sleep you received last night:\n");
    if (fgets(input, 100, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        printf("stdin error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (sscanf(input, "%lf", &hoursOfSleep) == 1)
    {
        // Got a double - break the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidBowling - Of cause OP should fix the format specifier first.

Answer (score 0):

You are using %f for taking input double value. %f is used for floats. For double, it is %lf.

```
scanf("%lf", &hoursOfSleep);
```

%d for int

%c for char

%s for string

%lld for long long int